# trying to add a prepend method to the linked list

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to create a prepend method that takes the value and insert it between the head and the next value in the linked list, and here is where I am at the moment, it only prints none < because of the print statement and then it prints just 1:

```
class Node:
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
            self.next = None


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return

        # Move to the tail (the last node)
        node = self.head
        while node.next:
            node = node.next

        node.next = Node(value)
        return

    def prepend(self,value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return
        else:
            holder = None
            self.head.next = holder
            #holder.next = holder
            print(holder)
        return

linked_list = LinkedList()
linked_list.append(1)
linked_list.append(2)
linked_list.append(4)
linked_list.prepend(5)
node = linked_list.head
while node:
    print(node.value)
    node = node.next
```

do you have any idea how to do that or fix my logic and please explean to me step by step how did you came up with the solution.
P.S: I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do:

```
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return

        # Move to the tail (the last node)
        node = self.head
        while node.next:
            node = node.next

        node.next = Node(value)
        return

    def prepend(self,value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return
        else:
            oldhead = self.head
            self.head = Node(value)
            self.head.next = oldhead
        return
```

Note that even if your append method is correct it is not efficient as you will have to see all the nodes in the linkedlist in order to append an element (so O(n) for your append insertion) and that what you call prepend is more efficient as it is a O(1) for inserting an element in the linkedlist.

Answer (score -1):

Were you trying to make a doubly linked list?

```
class DblNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None


class DLL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = self.tail = None

    def append(self, value):
        new_node = DblNode(value)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            print(f"First operation: New head node created: {self.head.value}\n")
            return

        new_node.prev = self.tail
        self.tail.next = new_node
        self.tail = new_node
        print(
            f"append function: Head added and tail node accounted. Values: {self.head.value}, {self.tail.value}\n"
        )

        node = self.head
        while node.next is not None:
            node = node.next

    def prepend(self, value):
        new_node = DblNode(value)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = new_node
            print(
                f"prepend function: Head added and tail node accounted. Values: {self.head.value}, {self.tail.value}\n"
            )
            return
        else:
            old_head = self.head
            old_tail = self.tail
            self.head = new_node
            self.head.next = old_head
            self.tail = new_node
            self.tail.prev = old_tail
            print(
                f"prepend function: Head added and tail node accounted. New values: {self.head.value}, {self.tail.value}. Previous values: {self.head.next.value} and {self.tail.prev.value}\n"
            )
        return
```

Test:

```
dll = DLL()
dll.append("First node")
dll.append("Second node")
dll.append("Third node")
dll.prepend("Fourth node")
dll.append("Plead tha fif node")
dll.prepend("Sith mode")
```

Output:

```
First operation: New head node created: First node

append function: Head added and tail node accounted. Values: First node, Second node

append function: Head added and tail node accounted. Values: First node, Third node

prepend function: Head added and tail node accounted. New values: Fourth node, Fourth node. Previous values: First node and Third node

append function: Head added and tail node accounted. Values: Fourth node, Plead tha fif node

prepend function: Head added and tail node accounted. New values: Sith mode, Sith mode. Previous values: Fourth node and Plead tha fif node
```